# Isn't open-source a two-edge sword?

Tags: updates, security, release-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wouldn’t writing an open source program make it available for anyone to freely hack and exploit, thus making it less secure?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33707/wouldnt-writing-an-open-source-program-make-it-available-for-anyone-to-freely-h)

I know that ubuntu is an open source OS, which is a great thing because all people can contribute. However, doesn't this make it more vulnerable to hackers also, as they can alter the code in a malicious way more easily?

Do the code or updates undergo some review before being released to the public?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that when an update is released, it is reviewed by the whole sayd community and then published. So i think it would be very hard to slip some bad code in when so many people who know their code, watch the code very deeply before it gets published.

Why it is a double-edged sword tough is that it's being developed by a big community who don't all work under one company with a single view on things. The devs here all have their own visions and everyone tries to push THEIRS through. So this basically makes the overall progress very slow.